# OperationalError: ('08S01', '[08S01] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]TCP Provider: The semaphore timeout period has expired

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas

I am loading data from Excel to SQL Server database.

```
import pyodbc
import sqlalchemy as sa
import pandas as pd
import urllib
conn='DRIVER={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};SERVER=*********.net;DATABASE=*****;UID=****;PWD=*****'
params = urllib.parse.quote_plus(conn)
engine = sa.create_engine("mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={}".format(params),fast_executemany=True)

df.to_sql('table_name')
```

I am getting this error:

> OperationalError: ('08S01', '[08S01] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]TCP Provider: The semaphore timeout period has expired.\r\n (121) (SQLExecute); [08S01] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Communication link failure (121)')

I have around 120 columns and 7k rows.

Comment: I think we already have some questions like this

Comment: yes, I tried to solve after seeing a couple of questions with none of them works for me. Please can anyone help me!

Comment: The error message is telling you that it's not able to connect to your SQL Server, it doesn't matter how big your tables are. Is the target SQL Server accessible on port tcp/1433? If it's listening on some other port number then you need to include that in your connection string, e.g. `SERVER=foo.example.net,2544;`.

Comment: It's not an obvious connection issue. I am able to write rows to the DB, but after about 8 minutes I get the same error.

Comment: Yes, I was also able to connect. But, some times it throws this error. I am not able to figure out still.